# Excel Formula to generate month Date of project

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working with a sales pipeline sheet and need a formula to generate the project start and end months based on invoice charges inputted in month columns. For example if a client delays a project and invoice months change, I'd ideally like the Project start and end month to update automatically as I update invoice months.

For example if I was to move 2000 and 1000 on the table below (row 1) to the Apr & May columns respectively, the formula would update Project start to Apr, and Project end to May.

| Project start | Project end | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | Feb | 2000 | 1000 |  |  |  |
| Jan | April | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 |  |
| [forumula to generate feb?] | [forumla to generate May?] | 500 | 500 | 500 | 500 | 500 |

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use the following cell formatting for the dates of your project (cell formatting, Custom):

```
mmm
```

In order to get to the next month, you can use the following formula:

```
=MONTH(DATEVALUE(DAY(B8)&"/"&MONTH(B8)+1&"/"&YEAR(B8)))
```

This takes the day, the month plus one and the year, and converts this into a new date from which the cell formatting will just show you the month. Be careful: this only works while working within the same year. In case you jump from December to January the next year, you need an `IF()` function to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these formulas for the start and end date - if you have Excel 365

`=INDEX($A$1:$G$1, MIN(FILTER(COLUMN(D2:G2),D2:G2<>"")))`

`=INDEX($A$1:$G$1, MAX(FILTER(COLUMN(D2:G2),D2:G2<>"")))`

- `COLUMN(D2:G2)` returns an array with the column indices of the invoice amounts.
- `FILTER` only returns those column indices that have an amount
- and finally `MIN` and `MAX` return the first and last column index
- this is then passed to INDEX on the header row.

[image]